# tkinter: Why am I getting a small window plus my main window and gridding is off? __init__ problem?

Tags: python, tkinter

Creates two windows and gridding is not correct. Some additional comments in the code initiation.
I have used this approach, without the super init with no problem, many times.
Advice appreciated.
Thanks

```
# timhockswender@gmail.com

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class constants_page(tk.Frame):     
    def __init__(self): 
        super(constants_page, self).__init__() # from stackoverflow
            # if not used error = 'constants_page' object has no attribute 'tk'
            # if used, another tiny window is opened
            # in addtion to the constants_page
        self.constants_page = tk.Tk() 
        self.constants_page.geometry("1000x500")   #width*Length
        self.constants_page.title("Owen's Unit Conversion App") 
        self.constants_page.configure(background='light blue')
        self.CreateWidgets()
        
    def CreateWidgets(self):
        self.value_label = ttk.Label(self.constants_page,text="Value----->" , width =10 )           
        self.value_label.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=1, sticky='nse')
            # Problem: not gridding properly
        
        self.title_label = ttk.Label(self.constants_page, text="Important Physical Constants", 
                anchor=tk.CENTER, font=("Arial",20)).grid(row=2, columnspan=2)
       
        
        for r in range(2):
            self.constants_page.rowconfigure(r, weight=1, uniform='row')
        for c in range(2):
           self.constants_page.columnconfigure(c, weight=1  )
def Show_Page():
    # Create the entire GUI program
    program = constants_page()
    program.mainloop()  
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
   Show_Page()
```

Comment: The code that you marked " from stackoverflow" is very old and outdated. Be sure to look at the date on online answers. Technology moves very fast; any answers more than 2 years old should be taken with a grain of salt, and over 6 years are almost certainly obsolete.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The super call expects you to provide a root window (an instance of tk.Tk()). If you don't provide one it defaults to the first root window opened, and if none has been opened yet then it helpfully opens one for you. A few lines later you open a second one yourself.

The easy fix is to remove the self.constants_page = tk.Tk() line. The proper fix is to make the Tk() instance outside of the class and pass it in. This allows you to use the Frame class itself to lay out widgets (use self instead of self.constants_page). Try this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class constants_page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        master.geometry("1000x500")   #width*Length
        master.title("Owen's Unit Conversion App")
        self.configure(background='light blue')
        self.CreateWidgets()

    def CreateWidgets(self):
        self.value_label = ttk.Label(self,text="Value----->" , width =10 )
        self.value_label.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=1, sticky='nse')

        self.title_label = ttk.Label(self, text="Important Physical Constants",
                anchor=tk.CENTER, font=("Arial",20)).grid(row=2, columnspan=2)

        for r in range(2):
            self.rowconfigure(r, weight=1, uniform='row')
        for c in range(2):
           self.columnconfigure(c, weight=1  )
           
def Show_Page():
    # Create the entire GUI program
    program = tk.Tk()
    win = constants_page(program)
    win.pack()
    program.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Show_Page()
```

Comment: Thanks, I’ll try it tomorrow. Your advice will help my other projects as well.

Comment: How can I modify to use grid properly? Changing win.pack to win.grid eliminates the widgets altogether and I need to use grid for other widgets.